# How to build a function that gives recent years higher weight?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-modeling

I want to have a value for users between 0-1 , that shows how much they like movies of specific type depending on how many movies they have watched and movie type ( comedy , etc ). I have a data of users watching movies during years.

data format

- user - movie - year - type

Was thinking of something like

user1_comdey =  number of comedy movies / number of watched movies

How can I use the years in the equation to make recent years more important ?

What we call this in Math ? I didn't know what best tags to use.

Thanks

Comment: First, welcome to math.SE! It sounds like you want to find weights for modelling a [time series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Long comment:**

Let's focus on one particular user, Alice, and on comedy movies, during a period of years $\{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n\},$ where $y_n$ is the most recent year. Assume Alice watched total $t_{i}$ movies during each year $i.$ Further more, she watched $c_{i}$ comedy movies during that year $i.$

To model Alice's preference of comedy movies, we can use the fraction
$$ \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} c_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} t_i} = \frac{\text{total number of comedy movies watched}}{\text{total number of movies watched}} $$

To add more weight to recent years, you can use a [weighted sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_function), and assign higher weights to recent years. In other words, Alice's comedy score would be:
$$ \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} w_i c_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} t_i} $$
where, for example, $$w_n = n, w_{n-1} = n-1, \ldots, w_1 = 1.$$
This weight assignment intuitively says that if Alice watched a comedy movie *recently* then we are going to count it *more than once.*

You can use different weight schemes. For example, you can read about exponential weights [here in this Wikipedia article on Moving Averages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

Comment: I was wondering about the min and max of the formula with weighted sums. It looks like it is not going to be between 0 and 1 as in the OP.

Comment: @EmmadKareem  The current range is $[0, x]$ (too lazy to figure out $x$). You can always rescale/normalize to $[0, 1].$

Comment: In fact, if we change the denominator to $\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i t_i,$ then it should be well within $[0, 1].$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: We call this function/equation a model ? and the below answer another model ? a model is a function that can be simple or complicated ?

Comment: @tnaser We would call this a model. Models are composed of functions, and constants, and mathematical expressions. There could be different models to solve the same problem. For example, the answer by Emre presents a different model.

Comment: How can we increase the weight ? I am trying on some data and get very small number like 0.00004 .

Comment: @tnaser I guess you need to post a new question, show us your model, your equations, and your sample data.

Comment: But I guess (without seeing your model), a temporary solution would be to scale all weights, i.e. $\dfrac{w_i}{\displaystyle\max_j {w_j}}$ should be fine.

Comment: didn't get that , what is j ?

Comment: $\max_j w_j$ is another was to say find the maximum weight among all the weights you computed.

Comment: What about using log , square root , 2^ , exp , e . I see them a lot but don't know why and how they were selected ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple [weighting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighting_function) is $w(movie)=\exp(t_{movie}-t_0)$, where $t_0$ is the present year and $t_{movie}$ is the year of the movie. For user $i$:

$u_i (comedy) \equiv \frac{1}{T_i} \sum_{k \in comedies} w_{movie_k}$

where $T_i=\sum_{n \in movies} w_{movie_n}$

This will give you a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Why to use exp ?

Comment: Because it is a simple function that smoothly tends to zero, and works with arbitrarily distant dates. If you want to tweak the attenuation rate, you can use $\exp(-a\Delta t)$ instead of just $\exp(-\Delta t)$, where $a$ is your tweaking knob.

Comment: What will be the difference between calculating , exp (-1) + exp(-2) than calculating exp(-3) ?

Comment: Should I sum the years than get the exp , or sum the exp ?

Comment: Sum the exponentials. The numerator is taken over the set of comedies. The denominator is taken over the set of all movies viewed by a particular user.