# Reduce the range of weighted sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-modeling

i am using this weighted sum

[How to build a function that gives recent years higher weight?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126082/how-to-build-a-function-that-gives-recent-years-higher-weight)

but I am getting values in the range 
1- 0.0000002

How can I reduce this range ? Make it something like 
1- 0.002 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are getting $x$ in the range $0.0000002 - 1$. Let $y$ = $((x - 0.0000002) * 0.998 / 0.9999998) + 0.002$. Now $y$ is in the range $0.002 - 1$. So just use $y$ in place of $x$ if you want values in that range.